# place a button on each row of flexigrid

Tags: php, cakephp, grid, flexigrid

I have implemented flexigrid in my cakePHP application. Now, I have given a edit button on the top. But i want to place edit button on each row. Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Flexigrid cell data can be anything including html code. Just add your html code to the data you supply to FlexiGrid and it should work.